# PHP Switch for star rating in wordpress

Tags: switch-statement

Trying to set up a star rating system from a number in a quick and simple way in my wordpress site.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$stars = $business['rating'];
settype($stars, "integer");

switch ($stars) {
    case 0:
        echo '<img src="' .  echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars0.png" />';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo '<img src="' .  echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars1.png" />';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo '<img src="' . echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars2.png" />';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo '<img src="' .  echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars3.png" />';
        break;
    case 4:
        echo '<img src="' .  echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars4.png" />';
        break;
    case 5:
        echo '<img src="' .  echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars5.png" />';
        break;
    }
    ?>
```

Seems like it should work but it just isn't coming up.

Comment: Any tips? I would like to get this to work soon.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run your code?

What are the possible values for $business['rating']?

If the possible values are all strings that do not begin with a number, then when $stars is converted to an integer, $stars will be converted to 0.

In this scenario, case 0 will always be matched.

Test out the theory by removing case 0 adding a

```
default:
  echo "No case matched: $stars for $business['rating']".
```

You also cannot add another echo statement, before the esc_url() function, and semicolon after the function when concatenating:

```
echo '<img src="' .  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )  . 'wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/stars0.png" />';
```

That might be a syntax error causing your code not to work.